# Struts 2 pagination,query syntax error

Tags: java, hibernate, pagination

I have an error while I am getting data from database.It looks like everything is fine but i get this error?Why?

Full Error

```
(org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException&#x3a; unexpected token&#x3a; 0 near line 1, column 47 &#x5b;from com.project.Data limit 0,10&#x5d; (Encoded))
```

DataAction.java

```
/**
             * To list Data
             *
             * @return String
             */
            public String listThrowException() {

                try{

                    //Getting Total records count from database...
                    pagination.setPreperties(facade.getDataCount());


                    //Getting data list from database
                    listData = facade.listData(pagination);

                    //Setting number of records in the particular page
                    pagination.setPage_records(listData.size());

                    logger.info(Logger.EVENT_SUCCESS,
                            "successfully viewed data list!");


                }catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(
                            Logger.EVENT_FAILURE,
                            "could not view data list, error: *"
                                    + e.getMessage() + "*");

                }

                return "success";
            }
```

DataService.java

```
     @Override
        public List<Data> listData(Pagination pagination){

            List<Data> list=new ArrayList<Data>();
            Query query;

            try {
                String excQuery = "from Data limit ";
                excQuery = pagination.getSQLQuery(excQuery);
                query = em.createQuery(excQuery);
                list = query.getResultList();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
            return list;



}
```

Pagination.java

```
public class Pagination {

    private long page_size = 0; 
    private int page_number = 0;
    private long total_records = 0;
    private int page_records = 0;
    private long start = 0;
    private long end = 0;
    private int total_pages = 0;


    public void setPreperties(long l){
        total_records = l;
        total_pages = (int) Math.ceil(((double)l / (double)page_size));
        start = ((page_size * page_number) - page_size);
        end = page_size*page_number;
        if(page_size==0){
            start = 0;
            end = l;
            total_pages = 1;
        }
    }

    public Pagination(int page_size, int page_number) {
        this.page_number = page_number;
        this.page_size = page_size;
    }

    public String getSQLQuery(String query) {
        query += getStart() + "," + getEnd();
        return query;
    }
///get and set methods
}
```

**My problem is that "limit" in Hql it is not supported.I use setFirstResults() setMaxResults() and it works.My question is a good example for implementing paginaton in your page. I refer this tutorial** http://prathap-puppala.blogspot.com/2011/06/struts-2-pagination-example.html I change only DateService.java**  **Good Luck!**

DateService.java

```
   @Override
        public List<Data> listData(Pagination pagination){

            List<Data> list=new ArrayList<Data>();
            Query query;

            try {
                String excQuery = "from Data ";
query = em.createQuery(excQuery).
    setFirstResult(pagination.getStart()).setMaxResults(pagination.getEnd());
                query = em.createQuery(excQuery);
                list = query.getResultList();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
            return list;



}
```

Comment: It is complaining about query syntax exception. You may set show_sql flag to true in config file and check the generated query syntax.

Comment: @Nambari checked and i have set before show_sql to true in config file.

Comment: "I checked" and what  is the generated sql? Have you tried to run it on some database GUI?

Comment: @Nambari, I use mysql GUI and when I write query there it is ok.

Comment: Again, I commented that, get SQL generated by hibernate and run it on mysql GUI, not the other way.

Comment: I run select * from  com.project.Data limit 0,10 in mysql,it doesn't run,it not make sens.Do you mean that hibernate get Data.java and not table in database?

Comment: I think You mixed some things here:
You probably want (by looking at listData signature) to get the Data objects. Are they an Entity? Show us the Data class. If You want to query Data table - You need to use NativeQuery, but then Im not sure it returns Data entities.

Comment: I solved my problem,i will edit my question now and show the problem.Thanks a lot for reply!